# Drupal Internationalization: How to translate taxonomy term additional field?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, internationalization, drupal-taxonomy

I have a taxonomy vocabulary with multilingual option: Localize. Terms are common for all languages, but their name and description may be localized.
And I've added long text field to terms of this vocabulary for additional description. When I go to Translate tab of this term I can translate only name and description.

How to translate additional fields of term?

**Note**: The [Entity translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module is enabled also, but I can't translate manually added fields of terms. By the way it has submodules: `Entity Translation Menu` and `Entity Translation Upgrade`. There is no Entity Translation Taxonomy.

Comment: Entity Translation module allows to translate term fields : https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation